# How do I select the first element of a filelist in ant?

Tags: ant

How do I take only the first element of an ant `<filelist>` and also `<echo>` that filename as a string?

Comment: I've discovered the `<first>` resource collection filter, but ${toString:...} eludes me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require external tasks

```
<project name="demo" default="run">

    <path id="files.path">
        <first>
            <filelist dir="dir1" files="foo.jar,file1.jar,file2.jar"/>
        </first>
    </path>

    <target name="run">
        <pathconvert property="path.output" refid="files.path"/>

        <echo message="Output: ${path.output}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: In ant, is a path the singular of files?

Comment: @joeforker No. a collection of files can be turned into a path. Paths are described in the ANT manual http://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#path. They are used to represent the Java classpath which the JVM uses to locate 3rd party classes accessible to the running program. Many ANT tasks accept paths so they're functionally similiar to filesets

Answer (score 0):

You will need [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/) and the trick used in the code is the fact that properties cannot be changed once they are set.

```
<for param="file">
    <path>
       <filelist 
        id="docfiles" 
        dir="toto"
        files="foo.xml
        bar.xml"/>
    </path>
    <sequential>
       <basename property="package" file="@{file}"/>
    </sequential>
</for>

<echo>${package}</echo>
```

**EDIT:** 
An alternative solution is using the break task from [Antelope](http://antelope.tigris.org/nonav/docs/manual/bk03ch05.html)